# System shuts down every 30 minutes

Tags: shutdown

My system shuts down every 30 minutes irrespective of whether it’s running on battery or connected to the mains. Initially, I thought it’s the OS that’s responsible for this issue. But I’ve installed different OS (Windows 7, 8 & 10), but the problem is still there. I am currently running on Windows 7. The laptop is a HP Elitebook 840.
Could this be a powercfg issue? What could be the problem pls?

Comment: Did you run `eventvwr.msc` and look under "Windows Protocols" --> "System"? There might be information there. The log viewer is a bit of a nuisance, admittedly, but you should be able to find an entry that says "system was shut down" somewhere, and there might be another one (like "power event XYZ received") nearby, probably the line above. That might give a clue as to where the problem might be located.